# Unable to run docker command from container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

There are three docker containers A,B and C.

I'm having my testsuites in C container targeting A and B containers. From container C i need to stop a service running in container B. How do i do that? I don't have docker installed in container C.

Ideally, i can run docker top  | grep servicename to fetch the services details. But, i'm wondering how do i get the docker installed in the container itself to execute the command.

Comment: Seems like you're looking for "docker in docker"

Answer (score 0):

Containers are intended to be isolated so I highly recommend against doing this. However it is possible to run docker in docker.

```
container-C:
image: debian:buster
working_dir: /
command: bash install-restart.sh
volumes:
  - ./install-restart.sh:/install-restart.sh
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Assume that the above container-C is a long running process that should restart Container B. The important thing here is to mount the volume for the docker.sock or the socket to that container. Then install dockerd on that container and restart other docker containers with the normal docker cli commands. So in this example install-restart.sh would be something like this:

```
  # Install and setup docker based on version provided
  curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
  add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
  apt-get update
  apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
  dockerd

  # Kick off restart
  while something == true:
  do
    docker restart $(docker ps -a | grep -v 'container-B' | awk 'NR>1 {print $1})
    sleep 43200
  done
```

The above would be the poorly written bash code for a loop that would restart a container named container-B.

Step 1: Mount docker.sock from the host to container-C
Step 2: Install docker and run daemon on container-C
Step 3: Use docker CLI commands to restart container-B

Answer (score 0):

Installing and running docker in docker has several problems and limitations.
[docker-in-docker](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci)

---

#### This can be solved by connecting docker.sock.

This allows you to run the host's docker command on your container_C.

---

Based on the ubuntu image, I will introduce a simple example.
(Map your container-C to ubuntu)

```
# install docker in your container-C's image
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

```sh
docker build -t myeongkil/ubuntu-docker .
docker run -d -i --name container_C -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock myeongkil/ubuntu-docker bash
docker exec -i -t container_C bash
docker ps -a
docker top <your_other_container_name> | grep <your_service_name>

# You can also check the processes through the docker exec command.
docker exec -i -t container_A sh -c "ps -a | grep <your_service_name>"
```

This is the result of a test I've done.

```
kmk@myeongkil $ docker exec -i -t container_C bash
root@ac41239bf894:/# docker exec -i -t peer0.org1.example.com sh -c "ps -a"

PID USER TIME COMMAND
    1 root 0:33 peer node start
   24 root 0:00 ps -a
```

Comment: Remember that, if you can run any `docker` command at all, it's all but trivial to root the entire host.  Think carefully before you give a container this level of privilege.